# Get eloquent model from DB including sub models

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm learning PHP and the Laravel framework and i'm getting stuck on loading some data from the database.

I have 2 models, Game and Player

Player model (curently empty):

```
class Player extends Model
{
}
```

Game model:

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public $Players = [];

    public function __construct(array $players = [])
    {
        $this->Players = $players;
    }

    public function SaveGame()
    {
        if($this->save()) {
        Log::info("New game created with id " . $this->id);
        }
        foreach ($this->Players as $key => $player){
            if ($this->Players()->save($player)){
            Log::info("player added to game with id " . $player->id);
            }
        }
    }

    static function GetGame($gameId)
    {
        Return Game::find($gameId);
    }

    public function Players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class );
    }
}
```

And i have a GameController:

```
class GameController extends Controller
{
   public function create()
    {
        $players = [];
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $player = new Player();
            array_push($players,$player);
        }

        $game = new Game($players);
        $game->SaveGame();

        return $game;
    }

    public function LoadGame($id)
    {
        $game = Game::GetGame($id);
        return $game;
    }
}
```

If i call the create() method of my GameController, it creates a game in my Game table and 3 players in the player table with the gameID of the corresponding game so i think the relation works fine.

But if i check the response of the create() method i get only this:

```
{
"updated_at": "2018-03-01 15:13:37",
"created_at": "2018-03-01 15:13:37",
"id": 3952
}
```

Also the LoadGame() function returns just the game. Actually i need the game with all its players inside. Something like this:

```
{
"updated_at": "2018-03-01 15:13:37",
"created_at": "2018-03-01 15:13:37",
"id": 3952,
"players":[
       {"name":"player1"},
       {"name":"player2"},
       {"name":"player3"},
     ],
}
```

What i'am doing wrong?/How do i get the wished result?

I'm also not sure if the Models are the right place to do the database actions and the controllers are the place to create the objects like i do in the posted code. If my "code structure" is not the best practice, some advice in this is also welcome!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships
Read the documentation carefully & try to follow the code style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so easy!, i found the solution by simply experimenting arround as i could not find a solution on the internet.

In the `Game` model I removed the

- `constructor` *(create own constructor in Laravel seems to be not recommended)*
- `SaveGame()` *(save my game in the controller now)*
- `GetGame()` *(useless, can use `Game::find(x)` in controller)*

In the `GameController` i changed my `create()` function a bit. This is the result:

```
public function create()
  {
      $game = new Game();          // creates a new game
      $game->Save();               // saves the new game into the db

      for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
          $player = new Player();              // creates a new player
          $game->Players()->Save($player);     // stores the player to the game in the db
      }
}
```

I also changed my LoadGame() method in my GameController to

```
public function LoadGame($id)
{
    $game = Game::find($id);        // Instead of doing this in a own method in my model 
    $game->players                  // adds the players to the game object for some reason
    return $game;                   // returns the game (as json) incl. all its players
}
```

This results in a json string what contains the game vars including a player array with its players. I dont understand why this is working but it is.

The weird thing is if i exchange  `$game->players` for `$game->Players()` or `$game->Players` (like the has many method in the model) it does not work. Maybe someone can explain me why this is? (as i cant find any clarifying documentation to this)

Answer (score 0):

To return the relationship you can use:

```
protected $appends = ['Players']
```

But to be honest, I think you may want to re-review the Laravel relationships docs to see how to do some of these things properly. Doing a bit of rewriting would make your life a bit easier in the future.

A couple notes for you:

1. Remove the `GetGame` method as it's arbitrary. By the time you've already pulled in the class `App\Game` you will be able to run the `find` method on it. You can just go: `App\Game::find($id)`
2. Remove the public $Players, as well as the construct, as these are unnecessary and breaks the relationship. Laravel makes it so that when you've created a relationship you can access it as if it's a variable within that class. Example: `$game->players`. You can kind of ignore the fact that the relationship is created as a method.

After doing those two things above, you can modify the protected $appends; variable and view your relationship when displaying the model.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i re-reviewed the relation documentation of eloquent and madesuggested changes (still have no idea why constructor or Players array breaks the relation). The good thing is that the relation still works `Game->find(x);` returns the game (without its players) and `Game->find(x)->Players;` returns its players. I can still not manage to get a game with all its props (so incl. players). Same for storing a game, now i need to store a game and add its players. I cannot find how i can manage this with the `protected appends` var.

Comment: Hmmmm... Let me do a bit more research and see if I can find something for ya